# WordPress regularly produces errors for cron.php, class-wp-hook.php and update.php

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, cron, updates

For a customer I set up a website in WordPress. The site got hacked and infected with malicious code, so I've re-uploaded all WordPress files and the files for the theme, changed all passwords, installed a security plugin and run several virus scans to remove every line of code, that was suspicious. The site worked normally after doing this, but now I get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot call assert() with string argument dynamically in /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-includes/cron.php on line 1 Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
function 'wp_cron' not found or invalid function name in /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_next_scheduled() in /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-includes/update.php:710 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): wp_schedule_update_checks('')
#1 /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-settings.php(450): do_action('init') 
#4 /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-config.php(126): require_once('/mnt/web107/d1/...')
#5 /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/mnt/web107/d1/...')
#6 /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/mnt/web107/d1/...')
#7 /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/index.php(22): require('/mnt/web107/d1/...')
#8 {main} thrown in /mnt/web107/d1/74/58360774/htdocs/wp-includes/update.php on line 710
```

The strange thing is, when the errors appear, I only need to re-upload all the WordPress core files and the website works properly for a few weeks again, but then the errors reappear.

Can someone explain me what causes these errors and how to fix them? I googled the errors but couldn't find a fix.

Comment: I'm curious, what version of Wordpress are you running

Comment: The latest (v 4.9.1). The theme and all plugins are also updated to the latest version, and PHP is v 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server's cron tasks, it must be something there that tries to execute something, and that's whats causing the error.

Sorry for not being more specific but every hosting company has his own panel.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: I called my hoster today and he told my that my hosting package doesn't include any cron tasks. The error appears from the WordPress files. Could the database also produce these errors?

Comment: Yes! It's stored in the database inside the table wp_options , under the option_name cron.

Comment: I compared an older version of the database with the current one, but couldn't find anything suspicious. Do you have any other suggestions what I could do now?

Comment: the thing would be, when u installed the new site, did you imported the old database? Probably you could make a new one, and import the data of the old one via the Wordpress Importer, and not importing it directly from the old DB
The other option is that a plugin is causing the issue (which i doubt), so disable plugins til the error is gone.
Besides those 2 options I can't think in anything else

Comment: So @Mario , was this issue solved? It's always good to choose a "valid" answer as a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The website got hacked and infected, so the the whole site was totally damaged. The only "solution" for this was to go back to an old backup and install various firewalls and malware scanners to prevent new malware infections.